# Okay gentlemen, we've voted to destroy the universe. Now, how do we do it? (Methods please)

Tags: space, apocalypse, universe

Still exploring some concepts from a world where an elder race has attained a godlike condition:

The Ruling Council has unanimously voted that the universe must be reset. The main justification is that they are the only civilization that ever reached the godlike condition in xxxxxxzillion years, that everything just keep repeating itself over and over, civilization A dies, civilization B is born, B advances and conquers C, and the only thing changing is the scale, groups, towns, nations, planets, systems...

Also, they have had enough and are bored.

## What methods could be used to end the universe?

Antimatter? Exotic matter? Flip the switch?

## Also, and extremely important so this doesn't become an idea generation question, HOW would they work?

Is the universe obliterated in a second? Does the destruction ride in a wave (like a ripple)? How long would it take given the size of the universe? Haha... Maybe its already destroyed and the wave just hasn't hit us yet.

Comment: While not answering the question: You - the elder race - why would you not just become extinct and safe yourself all the trouble of destroying the universe?

Comment: Because gives them something to do at last? Maybe they think that this universe is locked in a certain pattern and that pattern will keep happening unless something new starts? No civilization ever managed to create life so that counts as a failure? Also, another explanation is possible, but for not giving spoilers, there is a bigger reason for them to do it (or not).

Comment: Wait, I thought we were voting on breaking for lunch.

Comment: Ok, granted. In this case: let's get the apocalypse started (and safe me the trouble)!

Comment: "*Also, and extremely important so this doesn't become an idea generation question, HOW would they work?*" ....isn't enough to save it from being an idea generation question. Please see http://meta.worldbuilding.stackexchange.com/q/522/2072 for more information

Comment: I think that the question could be re-opened if it asks for a science-based explanation. After all, there are only so many ways the universe can end - mostly all speculative, admittedly.

Comment: What is meant by "destruction"? If you just want to end the formation of matter as it is like today, just wait. Theoretically the black holes will "eat" all matter one day.

Comment: Vacuum instability event? Quite good for your purpose because it can be done locally with sufficient technology and then spreads the whole universe.

Comment: @Sempie - probably not - current observations indicate continued accelerated expansion. What it does mean is that eventually everything will be too far away from anything else to be able to influence it (heat death)

Answer (score 9):

1. Find the lost city of [R'lyeh](http://tvtropes.org/pmwiki/pmwiki.php/Main/EldritchAbomination).
2. Knock on the door. Loudly.

That should be enough.

Comment: What if he snorts and go back to sleep? I need something that works... :)

Comment: Move the stars around until they are "right". No need to even find the lost city.